# Can I keep columns from breaking across pages?

Tags: microsoft-word-2007, layout

In Microsoft Word 2007, if I put a passage of text into a column layout that spans two pages, Word first puts everything that fits on the first page into a column layout on the first page, then the rest into a column layout on the second page. I want to prevent this breaking.

The question is difficult to phrase, so here's an example of what I want to accomplish:

Instead of

```
a c e
b d f
-----
g j m
h k n
i l o
```

I want the columns to be preserved across the page break, like so:

```
a f k
b g l
-----
c h m
d i n
e j o
```

Is this possible in Microsoft Word 2007?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use tables instead of columns. Insert a 3-column, 1 row table, delete its borders and put your text into it accordingly (you may have to manually section it into thirds.)

Answer (score 1):

Use a table instead of columns

Answer (score 0):

If you put a section break between the two pages and format each page with with columns your content should not span the page/section breaks.  You will have to break the data manually between the pages.

Comment: I'm a little unclear on what you mean exactly. Could you show me an example?

Answer (score 0):

The same question has been asked here.
[Use two columns in Microsoft Word separately](https://superuser.com/questions/377714/use-two-columns-in-microsoft-word-separately)
The answers suggested do not hit the mark, I am sorry. Word cannot do what is required, though it can be simulated with tables or text boxes. I am astonished at Zooks64's reply. The idea of having to break the data manually appals me. If this were a side by side translation, spanning twenty or so pages, and I wished to add a new paragraph onto page 1, it would be necessary to rework the manual data breaks on every page. Even the addition or removal of a single character could upset the page breaks. Word is not the tool to use unless this is a one off exercise. Publisher or WordPerfect will solve the problem though.